# Отсортированный список файлов по дате создания

Tags: java, android

Как можно получить список файлов с каталога в отсортированном списке по дате создания если можно используя класс File

Answer (score 5, accepted):

часть 1 - получить список файлов:

```
List<Files> files = new ArrayList<Files>();

File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "yourpath");
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile())
        files.add(f);
}
```

часть 2 - отсортировать:

```
Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
    }
});
```

Comment: Можете подсказать, вот есть список файлов большой, и есть имя файла, мне нужно узнать на каком порядковом номере хранится этот файл в этом массиве файлов который уже отсортирован, сравнение equal будет очень очень долго, и размер может увеличиваться?

Comment: Для начала если размер массива может увеличиваться то нужно юзать ArrayList а не массив. Во вторых думаю даже для миллиона файлов в списке equal будет работать предельно быстро. Если вам уж нужно хранить так много имен файлов то юзайте базу данных они для этого и предназначены - там и поиск будет быстро работать. Других альтернатив я не вижу.

Comment: Другой вопрос - зачем нужно знать порядковый номер?

Comment: Хорошо большое спасибо, тогда так и оставлю!

Comment: Просто мне нужно показывать в Viewpager показывать все картинки с определенного каталога, и если пользователь открыл определенный файл, чтобы я мог установить открытие именно этого файла в в том порядке который он был создан,

Comment: или короче говоря простой просмотрищк картинок

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [LastModifiedFileComparator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/comparator/package-summary.html), ну или подсмотреть как сделано, если нет жедания тащить весь commons-io в зависимости.